# Twoi images in one JQGRID cell - Which one clicked?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, click, cell, detect

I am trying to detect which icon was clicked when there are two within the same cell. I attach the database 'id' of the record to the 'ALT' value of the image.

Here is the code snippet from my JQGRID

```
colModel: [
            { name: 'id',label:'IMG',width: 50,fixed: true,formatter: function (cellvalue) {return "<img src='images/csd.png' alt='" + cellvalue + "' />" + "&nbsp <img src='images/pdf.jpg' alt=PDF-'" + cellvalue + "' />";}
```

Comment: why not a class to each icon?

Answer (score 1):

Add a class to the images and attach a click event to that class on `gridComplete` or `loadComplete` function.